# current location is wrong in google maps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps

am using googlemaps in my app to display user's current location ..

here's my code:

```
 self.locationManger.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManger.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    var currentlocation: CLLocation!

    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorized){
        currentlocation = locationManger.location
    }

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: currentlocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentlocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 15)
    mapView.camera=camera
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 90, right: 0)
```

and this is what i got:

[image]

the problem is that the pin is not on my real current location .. as shown in the screenshot .. my current location is in the red circle and the pin in the yellow circle ... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: is this your simulator screenshot? if it is then try to run it in a real device it will show u the exact location.

Comment: @MdRashedPervez no this is from a real device